# H10 error after deploying a Dancer2 app on heroku

Tags: perl, heroku, dancer

I've tried to deploy a small Dancer2 app on Heroku using the Perloku buildpack. The app is as simple as it gets is just The Dancer2 start page.
I seems to be successfully deployed but when i try to run it, it crashes . In the logs i have the following messages :

```
2016-06-18T10:39:36.571202+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finshed
2016-06-18T10:39:36.571190+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-06-18T10:39:40.377632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2016-06-18T10:39:43.357773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-18T10:39:45.136117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./Perloku`
2016-06-18T10:39:49.412546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
016-06-18T10:39:53.156458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-oasis-51363.herokuapp.com request_id=b4944cb8-e8a8-4d22-87ae-335dfa4d8701 fwd="89.123.89.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

In order to deploy i followed this steps:

1. In my terminal i typed the command dancer2 -a myapp.
2. cd myapp/bin then chmod +x app.psgi.
   3.In my main app directory inside the MAKEFILE.PL i added the lines:

   ```
   EXE_FILES     => ['/bin/app.psgi'],
   PREREQ_PM     => {
       YAML    => 1.15,
   },
   ```
3. Created an executable file called Perloku which has the following lines:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   ./bin/app.psgi daemon -l http://*:$PORT -m production
   ```
4. Deployed with these steps:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "Initial version"
   heroku create -s cedar --buildpack http://github.com/judofyr/perloku.git
   git push heroku master
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So i could't deploy my Dancer2 app on Heroku with the Perloku buildpack which worked for Mojolicius. So i worked around it using: miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl.
The steps for deployment where:
1)From my terminal in my main app dir i created a symbolic link with the comand:

```
ln -s bin/app.psgi
```

2)Inside my link i added the following code: `use lib 'lib'`

Then typed this commands in my terminal:

```
3)git init
4)git add .
5)git commit -m "Dancer on Heroku"
6)git heroku login 
7)heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/pnu/heroku-buildpack-perl
8)git push heroku master
```